# Double aggregation with distinct count in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have a collection which stores log documents.

**Is it possible to have multiple aggregations on different attributes?**

A document looks like this in it's purest form:

```
{
   _id : int,
   agent : string,
   username: string,
   date : string,
   type : int,
   subType: int
}
```

With the following query I can easily count all documents and group them by subtype for a specific type during a specific time period:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and : [
                {"date" : { $gte : new ISODate("2020-11-27T00:00:00.000Z")}}
                ,{"date" : { $lte : new ISODate("2020-11-27T23:59:59.000Z")}}
                ,{"type" : 906}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id" : '$subType',
            count: { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

My output so far is perfect:

```
{
   _id: 4,
   count: 5
}
```

However, what I want to do is to add *another* counter, which will also add the distinct count as a third attribute.

Let's say I want to append the resultset above with a third attribute as a distinct count of each username, so my resultset would contain the subType as _id, a count for the total amount of documents and a second counter that represents the amount of usernames that has entries. In my case, the number of people that somehow have created documents.

A "pseudo resultset" would look like:

```
{
   _id: 4,
   countOfDocumentsOfSubstype4: 5
   distinctCountOfUsernamesInDocumentsWithSubtype4: ?
}
```

**Does this makes any sense?**

Please help me improve the question as well, since it's difficult to google it when you're not a MongoDB expert.

Comment: Take a look at $facet https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/ , or provide sample documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group at the finest level, then perform a second grouping to achieve what you need:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and : [
                {"date" : { $gte : new ISODate("2020-11-27T00:00:00.000Z")}}
                ,{"date" : { $lte : new ISODate("2020-11-27T23:59:59.000Z")}}
                ,{"type" : 906}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id" : {
                subType : "$subType",
                username : "$username"
            },
            count: { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id" : "$_id.subType",
            "countOfDocumentsOfSubstype4" : {$sum : "$count"},
            "distinctCountOfUsernamesInDocumentsWithSubtype4" : {$sum : 1}
        }
    }
])
```

Here is the test cases I used:
[image: test cases]

And here is the aggregate result:
[image: aggregate result]

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I needed to see, and to solve my issue. Thanks a lot for a great answer!